# How to show an iron-data-table sorted

Tags: sorting, polymer, iron-data-table

I have a list of items , those items have a sortOrder number and a name
I want to show it sorted by sortOrder but this is not working

```
<iron-data-table id="entriesList"
    as="item"
    details-enabled
    items="{{entries}}">

    <data-table-column name="Media" width="360px" flex="2" sort-by="item.sortOrder"> [[item.name]]
    </data-table-column>
    <data-table-column name="Skip" flex="0">
        <paper-checkbox checked="{{item.skip}}"></paper-checkbox>
    </data-table-column>
</iron-data-table>
```

.

Comment: i have never used this element, but according to documentation, there is element `called data-table-column-sort` . https://saulis.github.io/iron-data-table/#data-table-column-sort . Could it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be:

```
<data-table-column name="Media" width="360px" flex="2" sort-by="sortOrder"> [[item.name]]
    </data-table-column>
```

Secondly, it won't autosort items for you, you need to sort *entries* by yourself, something like:

```
someFuncThatGeneratesEntries: function(entries) {
  return entries.sort((a, b) => Math.sign(a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder));
}
```